# No output when submitting a PHP form

Tags: php, html, forms

So I'm trying to create a basic form using HTML and PHP.

I have the form setup on my `contact.php` page, yet when I enter the values and submit, no values are shown on the `welcome.php` page, which is where it should appear.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    <p>Your Name: <input type="text" name="yourname" /> </p><br/>
    <p>E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>

    <p>Do you like this website?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="likeit" value="Yes" checked="checked" /> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="likeit" value="No" /> No
    <input type="radio" name="likeit" value="Not sure" /> Not sure</p>

    <p>Your comments:<br />
    <textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Send it!"></p>
</form>
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
<html>
<body>
    Your name is: <?php echo $_POST['yourname']; ?><br />
    Your e-mail: <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?><br />
    <br />
    Do you like this website? <?php echo $_POST['likeit']; ?><br />
    <br />
    Comments:<br />
    <?php echo $_POST['comments']; ?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button><a href="contact.php"><-- BACK</a></button>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** - I am following a tutorial from http://myphpform.com/php-form-tutorial.php so I do not know why it is not working for me. If you could help then that would be truely amazing.

Thanks, DTV

Comment: What browser are you using, and what server (if any)?

Comment: If you have a redirect after the form is posted, the values will no longer be available.

Comment: @Shikatsu Kagaminara I'm just using chrome and no server at the minute.

Comment: and @mopsyd I've tried just doing it on the one page but that doesn't work either. (If that was what you meant)

Comment: put `<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>` at the top of your page. If it consistently comes back empty, it's likely you have an apache rewrite that's redirecting and clearing your post values.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still not working. Neither the `contact.php` or the `welcome.php`. I'm probably doing something realy stupid here!!

Comment: Php won't work if you're not running the server/interpreter. Install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/pl/index.html) etc. If you want to test your code locally.

Comment: You probbaly don't have PHP running